# Added variable non-significant but model fit better?

Tags: interaction, model, nested-models

I ran two nested models: Model 1 without an interaction term, and model 2 with the interaction term. The interaction term turned out to be non-significant in model 2, but the model fit index (wald value) of model 2 is significantly better than model 1.

Any idea how or why a non-significant added interaction term can contribute to a better model fit? Any thoughts are appreciated!

Background info：I use STATA to run dynamic panel modeling (xtbond2). I compared the wald values of model 1 and model 2 based on the chi-square table and found the improvement of the value is larger than the threshold value when df=1, so this improvement is statistically significant.

Comment: This sounds like a coding error. Software outputs are almost always Wald tests (at least in R). Each parameter's p-value is computed as the Wald test of the full model and the model omitting that variable (except maybe the intercept).

Comment: Thanks! I compared the two nested models (models 1 and 2) based on the chi-square table and found the improvement is significant. That's why I said the model fit of model 2 is significantly better than model 1.

Comment: How did you compare the goodness of fit of the two models ? Did you use the sum of square residuals or an Akaike-like criterion ?

Comment: @Susan That is a likelihood ratio test, not a Wald test. When you try a Wald test (such as `lmtest::waldtest` in `R`), you should get matching p-values.

Comment: The output from Stata provides the wald value for each model, as well as the p-value associate with each model. Both model 1 and model 2 are statistically significant based on the p-value of the wald test. What confuses me is that the added interaction term was not significant, but the wald value of model 2 was significantly larger than model 1.

Comment: You didn't do a Wald test when you compared model 2 and model 1; you did a likelihood ratio test.

Comment: @Dave right, I did a likelihood ratio test based on the chi-square table to compare model 1 and 2. Did I do it wrong?

Comment: You correctly did a likelihood ratio test. If you meant to do a Wald test, then you did it wrong. If you want to compare that Wald test of model 1 and model 2 (an F-test of nested models), then you should do a Wald test, and that should give you the same p-value as the p-value on your interaction term in the model 2 summary (there could be slight rounding errors or the usual issues with doing math on a computer).

Comment: I meant to do a likelihood ratio test :) I wonder why the added interaction term is not significant, but the likelihood ratio test turns out to show the model with the added interaction term is significantly better? What might contribute to this significantly better model fit, despite the added interaction term is not significant?

Comment: You are testing two different ways. One asks for Wald's assessment; the other asks for the likelihood ratio assessment. They do not give the same answer. There is no contradiction. The p-values do not have to match, so they do not have to fall on the same side of your threshold. According to Wald, the interaction is insignificant, and model 2 has no better fit; according to the likelihood ratio, the interaction is significant, and model 2 has a better fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost every statistical software gives p-values in a regression model summary that are based on Wald testing. When you compared model 2 and model 1 using a chi-squared table, you compared them using a likelihood ratio test, which gives a different answer, particularly when the sample size is small.

I do not know STATA, but here is a simulation in R. Notice that the sample size of $25$ gives different p-values, but the sample size of $250,000$ gives nearly identical p-values. Indeed, asymptotics are at play.

```
library(lmtest)
set.seed(2021)
N <- 25
x1 <- runif(N)
x2 <- runif(N)
y <- x1 + x2 + 0*x1*x2+ rnorm(N, 0.2)
L_full <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1*x2)
L_reduced <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
summary(L_full)
lmtest::waldtest(L_full, L_reduced) # Wald
lmtest::lrtest(L_full, L_reduced) # Likelihood ratio
N <- 250000
x1 <- runif(N)
x2 <- runif(N)
y <- x1 + x2 + 0*x1*x2+ rnorm(N, 0.2)
L_full <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1*x2)
L_reduced <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2)
summary(L_full)
lmtest::waldtest(L_full, L_reduced) # Wald
lmtest::lrtest(L_full, L_reduced) # Likelihood ratio
```

In your case, according to Wald, the interaction is insignificant, and model 2 has no better fit; according to the likelihood ratio, the interaction is significant, and model 2 has a better fit. There is no contradiction.

Comment: Oh, I see. So do you think the wald test is more reliable in this case, that the interaction is not significant and the model fit is not better? Or the likelihood test is more reliable?

Comment: @Susan It depends on the kind of model you have. Perhaps you can ask in a separate question, since it really is a separate question.